# Disable HP DV6-3033CL quick launch buttons

Tags: laptop, keyboard, quicklaunch

HP DV6-3033CL got 5 keypads on the left of keyboards, which are for launching browser/outlook/printer/calculator/HP media. Not sure if those are called 'quick launch buttons'.

I usually mis-type those keys when trying to type tab/capslock/shift/ctrl which is really annoying. Is there any way to disable those keys? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Key Tweak](https://web.archive.org/web/20100729000347/http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/)** and remap keys to shift. To remap the keys of a non-standard keyboard use the Full Teach feature

EDIT:

Try this before using Key Tweak

- Run msconfig
- Under startup Tab, check for two programs HP QuickPlay and HP Quick launch buttons.
- If they exist un-check them and restart